# Removing header bar and reducing nav bar

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, woothemes

My website is: [www.mackandnicky.com](http://www.mackandnicky.com)

I am not able to remove the top header bar that displays the mail and contact number. And also I want to reduce the height and padding space from the main header (which contains logo and main nav).
Please help. Any suggestions ?

Comment: use this in your style.css  `.top-bar {
  display: none;
}`

Comment: What is the problem you have? You don't know how to do a padding?

Comment: You probably need to edit your theme's `header.php` and/or create a child theme and edit `header.php` there.